# trying to set focus on the form element by its id using after alert message but the jsp page submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

JavaScript Function:- the function is call on submit buttion.

```
function getFormElelemets(obj){
    var form = $(obj).closest('form'); // id of form tag related to the 
    var formid = form.attr('id');
    var name='sampledate'; // id of element for set focus
    alert(formid );     
    document.formid.name.focus();               
    return false;
}
```

Problem Statement:- the function get call successfully but after the alert if i press 'ok' the focus not move curser to the form element.servlate get called with and url shows all the paramter with there value.am generating multiple form dynamically with the unique id.Please provide solution.

Comment: `document.formid.name` is obviously a string (or undefined but `name` is could be defined DOM node property) . Just looks like your code is throwing unhandled error before `return false;` is called.  `focus is not a function`. Maybe you want instead: `document.formid[name].focus(); `. Anyway, whatever you are trying to do, just sounds like you are overcomplicating it

Comment: hi wolff i have tried what you suggested but still the focus not move to the  defined element id.

Comment: Which type of element is `#sampledate`? `input` or what? Is your harcoded ID just for example or this is what you wish to use in your production website? If so, just use ID selector as suggested in answer below, by eisbehr. And don't forget, IDs must be unique on document context. Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating issue in question itself

Comment: @A.Wolff you know that `formid` is a string too? ;) `document.formid[name].focus();`

Comment: @eisbehr Ya, sorry, indeed i meant: `window.formid[name].focus();`

Comment: yes , wolff it is a input type=date" sampledate" is id and it is unique for the form where the submit button get called.it is hardcoed id but the form am generating dynamically(am able to access all the id of form even form id).i want to use this in my production website.i have allready tried what eisbehr is suggested but still i have same probleam.

Comment: `unique for the form` BUT what about all document context???  Again provide MCVE

Comment: as i post the code for the am only getting the element for the particular form using  "var form = $(obj).closest('form');" for the document context the am not sure . can you please suggest me whats the wrong with my code. if i accessing id of the particular form where the submit pressed.

Comment: the problem is resolved by me using input type = button <input type="button" /> buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. has conjunction with JavaScript application.
whenever the <input type="submit"> buttons will submit the form .thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a jQuery `id` selector `#` and `.focus()` function:

```
function getFormElelemets(obj){
    var form = $(obj).closest('form');
    var formid = form.attr('id');
    var name = '#sampledate'; // id's starts with '#'

    alert(formid);
    $(name).focus(); // select element with jQuery and set focus

    return false;
}
```

Comment: hi eisbehr thanks for your response  i have tried what you suggested but still the focus not move to the defined element id. do u have any other suggestion.

Comment: Well, my code is devinitly correct. So please edit your answer and add your html structure and maybe more js code too. Then we can look what the problem is. By in general my code works. @someshpurohit

Comment: hi eisbehr am generating the html all the code dynamically in jsp file using the java . how can i show you the code .